# view_forum.php. Can't fix the get id

Tags: php, get, forum

There's an error at line `$id=$_GET['id'];` said that **Notice: Undefined index: id in D:\XAMPP\htdocs\view_topic.php on line 101**. I tried to change " $_GET " to " $_POST " but the error is still the same. Any help ?

I am trying to retrieve the id from the database and listed all the forum topic posted by users. Others php file can run smoothly. I got problem retrieving id of the post.

```
<?php
$host="localhost";
$username="root";
$password="";
$db_name="db";
$tbl_name="forum_question";

// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// get value of id that sent from address bar 
$id=$_GET['id'];
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE id='$id'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$rows=mysql_fetch_array($result);
?>
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: what is your url ? GET pick data from url.

Comment: How does this file get executed?  Is this an action to a form or is it directly called?  Based on that you should be able to retrieve appropriate key from either of the `$_POST` or `$_GET` globals.  Please add this information to your question.

Comment: Your code is also susceptible to sql injections.

Answer (score 0):

Always make use of the **`isset`** construct when assigning data to variables from outside world

```
if(isset($_GET['id']))
{
$id=$_GET['id'];
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE id='$id'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$rows=mysql_fetch_array($result);
}
else
{
echo "ID was not set. Let me go and check the form again !";
}
?>
```

Comment: Downvoted because of use of `mysql_*` functions and possible sql injection.

Answer (score 0):

This variable has to be set in your URL. You have to check if it's present:

```
<?php
$host = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$db_name = "db";
$tbl_name = "forum_question";

// Connect to server and select databse.
$db = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $db_name);

// get value of id that sent from address bar 
$id = isset($_GET['id']) ? (int) $_GET['id'] : 0;

if($id <> 0) {
    // TODO
    // 404 Not Found
} else {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE id='$id'";
    $row = $db->query($sql)->fetch_assoc();
    // TODO
    // Do Something with Data
}
```

Your URL must then be http://example.com/path/to/script.php?id=42

- I added `(int)`, so no sql injections are possible.
- I replaced `mysql_*` by MySQLi, see comment to your question.
- I removed quotes from variables in your query, you don't need them.

Comment: Switching from mysql_ to mysqli_ is somewhat pointless, if you still advocate interpolation and manual escaping/casting instead of  bound params / prepared statements (as per the unenticing standard comment).

Comment: You'll need it to use MySQL functions of versions >= 4.1